# How to tell if a page with scroll snapping is scrolled? (React js)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a page divided into sections with scroll snapping like `scroll-snap-align: start`. I really need to know if that page is scrolled.

These what I tried:

- Tried to logging `document.body.scrollTop`
- 

```
useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener("scroll",  () =>console.log(window.scrollY));
  },[]);
```

Both of them return nothing.

So, my questions are:

1. How to get scroll value in a scroll snapping page?
2. How to know if a scroll snapping page is scrolled?
3. How to tell if a scroll snapping page already at the top?